# Send Integers across sockets python

Tags: python, sockets

I have an integer, which i want to send across from a socket to another in python. Lets say this integer a=2. How do i send this integer across to a socket over a connection. 
Currently, i have done the following code:

```
server_socket.send(str(a))         #Server side


b=int(client_socket.recv(512))        #Client side
```

but the call to int() gives me error, saying that its not of valid length. i am basically not getting what argument to put in the recv() method.

Comment: What does print(client_socket.recv(512)) say?

Comment: gives an error somewhere. have to put in a keyboard interrupt

Comment: Also try ipython if you haven't, much simpler to debug in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending an 4-byte integer across the line but you are trying to receive 512 bytes, so it's just allocating an unallocated bit of memory like so:

000000000000000000000000000[...snip a bunch more bytes...]

....with the bytes it receives, so it looks like:

F34D5DD20000000000000000000[...snip a bunch more bytes...]

So you then have a 512-byte array of bytes, which can't be converted to an int. recv(4) instead, or better yet use a protocol that handle dynamic lengths (which is the only actually stable solution to this problem, you can't expect recv(4) to solve the problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a TCP connection you should remember that it's a streaming protocol and as such doesn't have any fixed sized messages. This means that when you call `recv` you might get less than the requested number of bytes, even less than what was sent with a single call to `send`. You can also receive all you requested if there was more calls to `send`.

All this means that your call to `recv` may return only part of the string that was sent, or more. Either way the string received was apparently not valid as an integer. To see what you *really* receive you should print it.